# PHP/MySQL get name where id = $result

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a consultation, where the id sent by url, and I need to display the name associated with this id, but by using this code it brings me all the names and just need the name associated with this id.

```
    <?php
require_once('../../../Connections/colegio.php');
if (!$colegio) {
    die('No pudo conectarse: ' . mysql_error());
}
$consulta = 'SELECT nombre_alumno FROM alumno';
$resultado = mysql_query($consulta);
if (!$resultado) {
    die('La consulta falló: ' . mysql_error());
}
/* obtención de filas en orden inverso */
for ($i = mysql_num_rows($resultado) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if (!mysql_data_seek($resultado, $i)) {
        echo "No se encuenta la fila $i: " . mysql_error() . "\n";
        continue;
    }

    if (!($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado))) {
        continue;
    }

    echo  $fila['nombre_alumno'] . "<br />\n";
}

mysql_free_result($resultado);
?>
```

Comment: Your query needs a `WHERE` clause. `SELECT nombre_alumno FROM alumno WHERE id='USER_ID_HERE';`

Comment: also assuming you have this url `http://foo.bar?user_id=12345`
so you can get the id like this:
`$_GET["user_id"]`

Comment: just to tell: `mysql_*` is depricated, have a look on `mysqli_*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understood this correcly but:

```
Select nombre_alumno FROM alumno where id='Your ID';
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments, user 2959229 and sadfiesch, what I mean is that already send for this ID, through consultation via url, but by making the query, the result brings me all data and only wish the data to send for, not if I explained well, I have made the above changes, but still brings me all data.

Comment: @AlexanderQuiroz can you post your ERM?